# Load XSD-validation-schema with includes and imports

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I would like to call an Open Journey Planner webservice and validate my requests I use for this. Unfortunately, I'm not able to load the XSD properly. My (simplified) code so far:

```
SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
Schema schema = factory.newSchema(new URL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/VDVde/OJP/master/OJP_Requests.xsd"));
schema.newValidator().validate(...);
```

However, I get the following error already when creating the schema: `org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/VDVde/OJP/master/OJP_Common.xsd; lineNumber: 58; columnNumber: 66; src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'siri:OperatorRefStructure' to a(n) 'type definition' component.`

Please note, that the error is only in OJP_**Common**.xsd and I'm loading OJP_**Requests**.xsd. This OJP_Common.xsd is referenced in the request `<xs:include schemaLocation="OJP_Common.xsd"/>` (via OJP_Fare.xsd). The missing siri:OperatorRefStructure however is only referenced via an `<xs:import namespace="http://www.siri.org.uk/siri" schemaLocation="./siri_model/siri_operator_support-v2.0.xsd"/>`.

I guess (and also partially confirmed this by debugging) only "includes" are read automatically and "imports" are not. How to change this so that I can load the whole XSD and so use it for validation?

---

Edit, minimal XSD leading to this error:

OJP_Requests.xsd:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:siri="http://www.siri.org.uk/siri" targetNamespace="http://www.vdv.de/ojp">
    <xs:import namespace="http://www.siri.org.uk/siri" schemaLocation="./siri_model/siri_modes-v1.1.xsd"/>
    <xs:import namespace="http://www.siri.org.uk/siri" schemaLocation="./siri_model/siri_operator_support-v2.0.xsd"/>
    <xs:element name="OperatorRef" type="siri:OperatorRefStructure"/>
</xs:schema>
```

siri_model/siri_modes-v1.1.xsd:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.siri.org.uk/siri"/>
```

siri_model/siri_operator_support-v2.0.xsd:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.siri.org.uk/siri">
    <xsd:complexType name="OperatorRefStructure"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

Interestingly, when I switch the order of the two imports in OJP_Requests.xsd, this minimal example is working. Unfortunately, the actual XSD structure is much larger and not under my control.

Comment: Please post a *complete* [mcve] that includes minimal XSDs that exhibit the problem so that we can help you debug.  Thanks.

Comment: Minimal depends on the point of view. :-) My 3 code lines already were a reproducible example. But I think I've also got your point, I've added a complete XSD structure.